# How to Select my own OutLook Calender instead of default calendar to Redemption loader appointmentitem

Tags: vb.net, outlook, calendar, outlook-redemption

Am using Redemption library to sync appointments to Outlook calendar

Below is the Vb code to set default calendar to Outlook Appointment Item .

By default it is selecting Default calendar from Outlook . But i need to set my own calendar with name of calendar which i added in Outlook to Appointment Item.

```
Dim objAppointmentRecord As Object 'Outlook.AppointmentItem

 objAppointmentRecord = Redemption.RedemptionLoader.new_SafeAppointmentItem

 Dim objAppointmentFolder As Object 'Outlook.MAPIFolder

 objAppointmentFolder = Redemption.RedemptionLoader.new_MAPIFolder

 objAppointmentFolder = modMain.gobjMAPI.GetDefaultFolder(9)

 objAppointmentRecord = objAppointmentFolder.Items.Add ' In this line it is setting default calendar .
```

I tried to set my calendar through loop to set Test Calendar to objAppointmentRecord .

```
        Dim objNavGroup
        Dim objNavFolder
        Dim objNavMod
        Dim objSelectedCal = objAppointmentFolder.Items
        objNavMod = objAppointmentFolder.GetExplorer.NavigationPane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(1)
        For Each objNavGroup In objNavMod.NavigationGroups
            For Each objNavFolder In objNavGroup.NavigationFolders
                If objNavFolder.DisplayName = "TestCalendar" Then
                    objSelectedCal = objNavFolder
                    GoTo ExitFromCalLoop
                End If
            Next
        Next
ExitFromCalLoop:
 objAppointmentRecord = Redemption.RedemptionLoader.new_MAPIFolder.Items.Add(objSelectedCal)
```

Here in last line setting objAppointmentRecord  with my TestCalendar but this approach didn't  select my calendar .

Is there any way to select calendar to objAppointmentRecord  directly or any new approach please suggest me .

I look forward to your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got answer from Redumption support to select user defined calendar in Outlook to sync

```
objAppointmentFolder = modMain.gobjMAPI.GetDefaultFolder(9).Folders.Item(“My Folder Name”)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do not use the `Redemption.MAPIFolder` object - it is deprecated. Create an instance of the `RDOSession` object and set its `MAPIOBJECT` property to the value returned by `Namespace.MAPIOBJECT`.

If you have `Outlook.MAPIFolder` object from OOM and you want to open it in Redemption, call `RDOSession.GetFolderFromID` or `RDOSession.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject`.